# How many elements are there in the set $S=\{(X,Y,Z)\mid X\subseteq Y\subseteq Z\subseteq U\}$ where $U$ is some fixed set with $n$ elements?

Tags: combinatorics

How many elements are there in the set $$S=\{(X,Y,Z)\mid X\subseteq Y\subseteq Z\subseteq U\},$$ where
$U=\{u_1,u_2,...,u_n\}$ is some fixed set with $n$ elements?

For each element $x$ in $U$, there are four possibilities:

$x$ is in $X\cap Y\cap Z$.

x is in $Y\cap Z$.

x is in $Z\backslash(Y\cup X)$.

x is not in $Z$ (so is in $U\backslash Z$).

For each element in $U$, there are $4$ choices and there are $n$ elements in $U$.

Therefore, the total number of elements in the set $S$ is $4^n$, where $n$ is the number of elements in the fixed set $U$. Do you think that's a good approach and how would you solve the problem? Other solutions are welcome.

Comment: This is exactly right and is the suggested approach.

Comment: @JMoravitz: the OP's argument isn't quite right as stated. See my answer.

Comment: And in any case, there is not **the** suggested approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is close but two of the cases you consider aren't independent: if $x \in X \cap Y \cap Z$, then $x \in Y \cap Z$, so you can't conclude that you have $4^n$ choices. To fix this, observe that because we have $X \subseteq Y \subseteq Z \subseteq U$, the four sets $X$, $Y \setminus X$, $Z \setminus Y$ and $U \setminus Z$ are pairwise disjoint and their union is $U$. Also, if we have specified for each $x \in U$, which of these four sets $x$ belongs to, then we have uniquely determined the tuple $(X, Y, Z)$. Thus we have $4$ independent choices for each of the $n$ elements of $U$, giving us $4^n$ as the number of possible members $(X, Y, Z)$ of $S$.

Comment: Or more succinctly, $x$ is in none, one, two, or three of the sets $X$, $Y$, $Z$.

Comment: @user14111: I was deliberately not being succinct in an attempt to make it clear exactly what is going on $\ddot{\smile}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Bijection Proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_proof). The map
$$\mathrm{Map}\bigl(U,\{1,2,3,4\}\bigr) \to S,\quad f \mapsto \Bigl(f^{-1}(\{1\}),f^{-1}(\{1,2\}),f^{-1}(\{1,2,3\})\Bigr)$$
is a bijection, since you can write down an inverse map: Given $(X,Y,Z) \in S$, we define $f : U \to \{1,2,3,4\}$ by $f(u)=1$ for $u \in X$, else: $f(u)=2$ if $u \in Y$, else: $f(u)=3$ if $u \in Z$, else: $f(u)=4$.

Thus,
$$\# S = \# \mathrm{Map}\bigl(U,\{1,2,3,4\}\bigr) = 4^n.$$

And this method immediately generalizes. The number of increasing chains of $m$ subsets in an $n$-element set is $(m+1)^n$, since they are in bijection with maps to $\{1,\dotsc,m+1\}$.

Comment: And the category-theoretic minded people will of course immediately notice that this is equivalent to finding the *universal* increasing chain of $m$ subsets. The answer is $\{1\} \subseteq \{1,2\} \subseteq \cdots \subseteq \{1,\dotsc,m\}$ inside of $\{1,\dotsc,m+1\}$. So the functor mapping a set $U$ to the set of increasing chains of $m$ subsets is representable, and *hence* their number is easy to determine. Category theory is useful - everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to look at the problem is in terms of choosing a certain amount of elements from $U$ to go into $X$, $Y$ and $Z$.

Let $|X| = N_X$, $|Y \backslash X| = N_Y$ and $|Z\backslash Y| = N_Z$. In other words, we first choose $N_X \in \{0,\ldots,n\}$ elements to go into $X$. These are automatically in $Y$, so we choose an additional $N_Y \in \{0,\ldots,n-N_X\}$ elements, and finally we choose $N_Z \in \{0,\ldots,n-N_X-N_Y\}$ elements to add into $Z$.

This first choice of elements can be done in $\binom{n}{N_X}$ ways, the second in $\binom{n-N_X}{N_Y}$ ways and the third in $\binom{n-N_X-N_Y}{N_Z}$ ways. Now we simply sum over all possible tuples $(N_X,N_Y,N_Z)$, keeping in mind their respective upper bounds.

After some minor simplification, we have a total of
$$
\sum_{N_X = 0}^n \sum_{N_Y = 0}^{n-N_X} \sum_{N_Z = 0}^{n-N_X-N_Y} \frac{n!}{N_X! N_Y! N_Z! (n-N_X-N_Y-N_Z)!}
$$
possible tuples $(X,Y,Z)$ s.t. $X\subseteq Y \subseteq Z \subseteq U$.

Comment: The next step is to actually compute the sum.

Comment: A fine example of the wonderful word "simply" being used to to describe a calculation that's "hard as hell".